# Why there is no std::erase?

Tags: c++, stl

While reading the STL I realized that there is no `std::erase` provided. I am not really sure why it is not there. A valid use case is following

```
std::vector<int> odd { 1, 3, 5, 3, 9, 11, 5, 17 };
std::sort(odd.begin(), odd.end());
std::erase(std::unique(odd.begin(), odd.end()), odd.end());
```

It is embedded in every container though. If performance is the reason, in a manner that if the objects are contiguous they could be deleted in one shot. But I guess that is doable with help template specialization.

Comment: I suppose that, if the answer is "it is possible to implement but C++ decide not to do it", this question would be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: Note: Java _does_ provide the ability to reomve items from a collection via iterators; however, many collections are not mutable so this operation doesn't always work, leading to an inconsistent API.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How would it work? It only accepts a pair of iterators. Iterators don't *have* to keep a reference to their container (a vector's iterators can be mere aliases for pointers).

So how would the algorithm *modify* the container itself? It needs that access.

It must be a member function.

Answer (score 12):

[Uniform container erasure](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4273.htm) was added to std/experimental int the Library Fundamentals 2 TS at the end of 2014.  This was voted into the standard recently for C++-2a but even the draft from github doesn't show it yet.  I know gcc, clang, and Visual Studio support experimental.

So instead of your usual container include one of these versions:

```
<experimental/deque>
<experimental/forward_list>
<experimental/list>
<experimental/map>
<experimental/set>
<experimental/string>
<experimental/unordered_map>
<experimental/unordered_set>
<experimental/vector>
```

These are the signatures from from [a more recent paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4481.html#container.erasure):

```
  // <experimental/string>
  template <class charT, class traits, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(basic_string<charT, traits, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class charT, class traits, class A, class U>
    void erase(basic_string<charT, traits, A>& c, const U& value);

  // <experimental/deque>
  template <class T, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(deque<T, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class T, class A, class U>
    void erase(deque<T, A>& c, const U& value);

  // <experimental/vector>
  template <class T, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(vector<T, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class T, class A, class U>
    void erase(vector<T, A>& c, const U& value);

  // <experimental/forward_list>
  template <class T, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(forward_list<T, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class T, class A, class U>
    void erase(forward_list<T, A>& c, const U& value);

  // <experimental/list>
  template <class T, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(list<T, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class T, class A, class U>
    void erase(list<T, A>& c, const U& value);

  // <experimental/map>
  template <class K, class T, class C, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(map<K, T, C, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class K, class T, class C, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(multimap<K, T, C, A>& c, Predicate pred);

  // <experimental/set>
  template <class K, class C, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(set<K, C, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class K, class C, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(multiset<K, C, A>& c, Predicate pred);

  // <experimental/unordered_map>
  template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(unordered_multimap<K, T, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred);

  // <experimental/unordered_set>
  template <class K, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(unordered_set<K, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred);
  template <class K, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
    void erase_if(unordered_multiset<K, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred);
```

Comment: is it part of std c++17?

Comment: I think it's still in std/experimental unfortunately. I'll edit my post.

Comment: yes, maybe that is the reason it is not listed here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: This proposal and more would have been redundant if [p0251r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0251r0.pdf) had gone through. Shame. But, anyway, +1.

Comment: This was added to C++20 and is implemented in gcc-9, clang-7, Visual studion recent.

Answer (score 7):

The glue between sequences and algorithms are iterators (thanks to @Pete Becker for pointing me to the right term here). They are boiled down to the minimal functionality necessary for powerful algorithms that can be applied to multiple sequence (container) types. An example is such a snippet:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::list<int> lst;

std::copy(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), std::back_inserter(lst));
std::copy(lst.cbegin(), lst.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Here, `std::copy` can be implemented independently of the specific sequence type it operates on, because it workes with iterators that are meant to do two things: **traverse** a sequence and provide **access** to its elements.

However, this ships with a limitation when elements shall be **deleted** from a container.

The need to do so while leveraging a (`std`-)algorithm is common enough to give rise to the [erase remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) being a well-known pattern or range libraries that take advantage of whole containers being passed to algorithms:

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext.hpp>

std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4};

boost::remove_erase(vec, 3);
```

The last function invocation can actually delete the element with value `3` from the container, because no information has been hidden in that function call. In contrast, the family of `*begin`/`*end` (member) functions does exactly that: hiding information behind an abstraction.

Comment: The abstraction is a bit more abstract than that. Iterators are the glue between **sequences** and algorithms. Containers are one way of managing sequences, but they are not the only way. For example, you can create a pair of iterators that walk through an input stream; very few people would call an input stream a container. +1 anyway.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for this hint! I improved the answer.

Comment: Iirc there is a proposal to add (an overload set of) `std::erase_if`, in the vein of `boost::remove_erase`